# Python pandas: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Tags: python, macos, pandas, numpy

I am trying to run a python script and I am getting the following error;

```
import pandas as pd
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

both numpy and  pandas were successfully installed using pip. How can I fix this?

Comment: It is said numpy dependency is missing. You need to install it beforehand

Comment: @user2682877 I installed numpy but It's still giving the same error.

Comment: Did you install numpy for Python2 or Python3? What happens, if you do `import numpy`?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen I am using python 2.7. If `import numpy` nothing happens, It displays that error when I import with pandas as well

Comment: thank you @tommy.carstensen and @user2682877, it is now working. I decided to add `import numpy` before `import pandas`. Somehow it started working though I still need to know what caused the error

Comment: When you say "but I know I installed numpy", do you have pyenv, Anaconda or other virtual environments? Maybe it got installed under one of the other environments. Prove to us that it got installed by doing `import numpy as np` then check `np.__path__`, and make sure you picked up the version you thought you did.

Answer (score 2):

This error will occur when multiple versions of numpy are installed. Check to make sure you only have one version of numpy installed. You can make a test file to check this if you don't want to look through the directories:

```
import numpy
print("Numpy imported")
```

If you get an error saying that multiple versions of numpy were detected, then you have multiple versions of numpy installed.

You can fix this by repeatedly calling
`pip uninstall numpy` 
until all versions are uninstalled and then use
`pip install numpy` 
to get only the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Similar thing happened to me. Here is what I did:

Use a `.whl` file to install `numpy+KML` KML is important and I believe was not getting installed when I got a similar error. After that use another `.whl` file to install `pandas`. I used the following for the files: [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

A quick search will get you the right method to install whl files.

Make sure to get the correct whl files.